# Attach a already created pdf with a new pdf generated with DOM PDF in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am creating a PDF file using DOM pdf and codeigniter as my framework. In that PDF i want to attach already saved PDF's on my server at the end of newly created PDF file. Is that possible with DOM PDF to create a PDF like that.

Answer (score 0):

Presently DOM PDF will not support for merging two pdf files

You can do with PDFTK.

Or
Refer this :

[Merge multiple PDF files into one in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855712/merge-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-in-php)